# Как открыть Activity2 из базового класса?

Tags: android-sdk, android

Здравствуйте.

Имеется базовый класс BaseActivity extends Activity. От данного класса наследуются все остальные Activity.

1. Как сделать в базовом классе так, что бы при старте если флаг (boolean переменная которая берется из сохраненных настроек SharedPreferences) true то запускалась сразу не MAIN activity, а Activity2?
2. Как сделать кнопку возврата сразу в MAIN activity и закрыть все открытые до этого activity (если пользователь находится в других activity)?

Для вызова activity использую Intent:

```
Intent newsIntent = new Intent(this, NewsActivity.class);
        startActivity(newsIntent);
```

В общем нужна Ваша помщь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем вот решение данных вопросов:

1. `if(flag && this.getLocalClassName().equals(StartActivity.class.getSimpleName()))
           {
               Intent activity2Intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
               startActivity(activity2Intent );
           }`

в данную проверку я добавил в метод onCreate базового класса (BaseActivity). Во втором условии (this.getLocalClassName().equals(StartActivity.class.getSimpleName()))) я анализирую  имя класса текущей активити и сравниваю его с именем класса стартовой активити, т.е. если запускается стартовая активити и флаг true, то мы сразу переходим на Activity2.
по первому вопросу если что-то не понятно прочитайте комментарии к первому ответу либо спрашивайте, обязательно отвечу.

2.
`Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, StartActivity.class);
            startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            flag = false;
            startActivity(startIntent);`

в данном случае я запускаю стартовую активити и удаляю из стека все активити которые были открыты после. Для этого я использую флаг FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP (более подробно см. в официальной документации [FLAG-ACTIVITY-CLEAR-TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))

Answer (score 0):

Это называется сломай себе моск. Если я всё правильно понял, то вам нужно вместо обычных вызовов активити использовать startActivityforResult [Starting Activities and Getting Results](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) Тогда при завершении топовой активити вы сможете передавать флаг заверешения всем нижележащим активити и при получении такого флага завершать и их тоже. По первому вопросу мне ещё менее ясно, но в любом случае вы можете запуская стартовую активити проверять этот нужный вам параметр и соответственно продолжать с ней работать или закрыть её и открыть нужную

Comment: Уточню первый вопрос. Имеется базовый класс BaseActivity extends Activity, который ни к чему не привязан и служит как обертка для того что бы перед загрузкой какой либо активити произвести еще какие-нибудь действия, в частности дополнен метод onCreate и onStart. Так же имется StartActivity extends BaseActivity которая уже в свою очередь наследуется от базового каласса (BaseActivity) и в манифесте прописана как android.intent.action.MAIN и android.intent.category.LAUNCHER, т.е. стартовый экран для приложения.

Comment: Я пытался сделать в BaseActivity (т.к. его методы будут вызваны при первом запуске) следующее if(flag) Intent activity2Intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class); startActivity(activity2Intent); в onCreate и onStart, но в итоге запускался только черный экран...

Comment: ыыы.. решил добить уточнением?))

Comment: Дико извеняюсь!!! пока писал понял в чем ошибка т.к. у меня все активити наследуются от BaseActivity, то после перехода на Activity2 происходит зацикливание! Т.е. мне надо как-то дополнить условие if проверкой что в данный момент запустилось именно StartActivity...

Comment: По второму вопросу нашел такое решение :) 
Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, StartActivity.class);
startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(startIntent);

Comment: обращай внимание на стек активити, а то я одно время намучился с правильным завершением